# How do I launch a CGI script from a WSGI handler?

Tags: python, cgi, wsgi, bugzilla

I'm trying to make a small testing server for Bugzilla so I can test out changes I make before they are deployed to the main Apache based server. I'm most familiar with Python, and I was wanting to make Python's built-in HTTP server run Bugzilla's CGI programs.

Unfortunately, Bugzilla has lots more than CGI apps. It has a bunch of css and other data that is served up directly. This means the handler needs to deal with those as well. I would like to set up a WSGI handler that looks at the request URL and appropriately routes the request to either one of the Bugzilla CGI scripts or pulls the data directly from the filesystem.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I want to do? If there isn't, is there a WSGI app out there already that will set up a CGI environment and call out to a CGI app via Python's `subprocess` module?

Comment: It's probably a lot easier to just set up a small configuration file for httpd that does what you need.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I don't understand how that would be at all easier. Apache has always seemed like a hugely painful beast to get to run at all. All web apps I've worked on that were at all pleasant had a tiny web server you could start up for development purposes.

Comment: If configuring Apache is the problem you may want to try [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Comment: @EmilM: I just wrote my own small Python webserver and subclassed `CGIHTTPRequestHander`. It was only slightly harder to write than an Apache config file, and I feel that I have a lot more control over exactly what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that works, though it's rather ugly and kind of slow. It demands a separate `CGIApplication` object for each CGI script you want to run. So if you have a directory full of them, you will need to instantiate a different `CGIApplication` object for each one. When you instantiate it, of course, is up to you. You can choose to instantiate new ones for every request, but you will likely save a bit of time if you somehow avoid this.

```
import os
import os.path as _osp
import re
import subprocess
import io
import email.parser

env_forward = re.compile('^[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*$')
header_match = re.compile(b'^(.*?\\n[ \\t\\r]*\\n)(.*)$', re.M | re.S)
env_whitelist = frozenset(('AUTH_TYPE', 'CONTENT_LENGTH', 'CONTENT_TYPE',
                           'DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'QUERY_STRING', 'PATH_INFO',
                           'PATH_TRANSLATED', 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'REMOTE_PORT',
                           'REMOTE_IDENT', 'REMOTE_USER', 'REQUEST_METHOD',
                           'REQUEST_URI', 'SCRIPT_NAME',
                           'SERVER_ADDR', 'SERVER_ADMIN', 'SERVER_NAME',
                           'SERVER_PORT', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL',
                           'SERVER_SIGNATURE', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE'))

class CGIApplication(object):
    def __init__(self, appfname):
        self._appfname = _osp.abspath(appfname)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_respose):
        appenv = {item[0]: item[1] \
                      for item in environ.items() \
                      if ((item[0] in env_whitelist) or
                          item[0].startswith('HTTP_'))}
        appenv['GATEWAY_INTERFACE'] = 'CGI/1.1'
        appenv['PATH'] = '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
        appenv['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = self._appfname
        nbytes_for_cgi = appenv.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '')
        nbytes_for_cgi = (int(nbytes_for_cgi) if nbytes_for_cgi != '' else 0)

        args = [self._appfname]
        query = environ.get('QUERY_STRING', None)
        query = query.replace('+', ' ')
        if '=' not in query:
            args.append(query)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args,
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                env = appenv,
                                cwd = _osp.dirname(self._appfname))
        bytes_read = 0
        data_for_cgi = io.BytesIO()
        while bytes_read < nbytes_for_cgi:
            data = environ['wsgi.input'].read(nbytes_for_cgi - bytes_read)
            bytes_read += len(data)
            data_for_cgi.write(data)
            data = None
        data_for_cgi = data_for_cgi.getvalue()
        output, errdata = proc.communicate(data_for_cgi)
        data_for_cgi = None
        proc.stdin.close()
        proc.stdout.close()
        proc.stderr.close()
        try:
            errdata = errdata.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            errdata = errdata.decode('iso8859-1')
        environ['wsgi.errors'].write(errdata)
        errdata = None
        if proc.returncode != 0:
            start_respose('500 Internal Server Error',
                          [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
            return (b"CGI application died with non-zero return code.\n",)
        else:
            output_hdr = header_match.match(output)
            output_hdr, output = output_hdr.groups()
            parser = email.parser.HeaderParser()
            headers = parser.parsestr(output_hdr.decode('iso8859-1'))
            status = headers.get_all('Status', ['200 OK'])[-1]
            del headers['Status']
            start_respose(status, list(headers.items()))
            return (output,)
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but it's the only thing that solved my problem. If I write a gateway myself, I'll stick it here.

Comment: And I have written a gateway myself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using pybugz? http://www.liquidx.net/pybugz/

http://code.google.com/p/pybugz/

Also, setting up WSGI through Django and AppEngine is really easy. Pretty quick to install and might be worth using as a work around. That would get you a testing server that should be able to handle bugzilla's cgi, css, etc.

Good Luck

Comment: Not yet, but I wouldn't want to re-write the whole Bugzilla UI in terms of pybugz anyway. And I want a generic WSGI->CGI gateway specifically because a wide variety of different small Python web servers are geared towards serving up WSGI. I don't want a specific Python web server that can serve up with WSGI and CGI. I want a gateway so I have my pick of web servers.